# Custom HTML element is not rendered on the screen while successfully being rendered in the HTML tree

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I created a custom HTML element:

```
class PieChart extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    } 

    init() {
        this.#render();
    }

    #render() {
        const circleElement = document.createElement("circle");
        circleElement.setAttribute("cx", 100);
        circleElement.setAttribute("cy", 100);
        circleElement.setAttribute("r", 80);
        circleElement.setAttribute("fill", "none");
        circleElement.setAttribute("stroke", "green");
        circleElement.setAttribute("stroke-width", 40);
        circleElement.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `502.85 502.85`);

        const svgElement = document.createElement("svg");
        svgElement.style.display = "block";
        svgElement.style.width = "inherit";
        svgElement.style.height = "inherit";
        svgElement.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 200 200`);
        svgElement.append(circleElement);

        this.appendChild(svgElement);

        this.style.display  = "block";
        this.style.width = "200px";
        this.style.height = "200px";
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        const event = new CustomEvent("init", {
            bubbles: true
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}

customElements.define(
    "pie-chart",
    PieChart
);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello!</p>
    <pie-chart></pie-chart>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    document.body.addEventListener("init", (pEvent) => {
        const element = pEvent.target;
        element.init(this);
    });
</script>
```

This code is executed without any problems and the custom element is rendered in the DOM. However, the circle is not rendered on the screen.

[image]

PS: if I open DOM in a browser and click "Edit As HTML" on the PieChart element and change anything inside and save it, the circle appears. I used this pattern several times before and there were not problems, but this time is the first one when I use SVG element.

Comment: This seems a very odd way to define a custom element: your `<pie-chart>` is already in the DOM, it should just build its own shadow DOM as part of the connectedCallback. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [not really how you create a custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements). Create a shadow DOM in the connectedCallback, and the browser does the rest, including "activating" any custom elements that already exist on the page by the time you register their tags. No custom event dispatching, the custom element system was designed to take care of this for you.

```js
const createSVGElement = tag => document.createElementNS(`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, tag);

class PieChart extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  } 

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log(`let's go`);
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    const circleElement = createSVGElement("circle");
    circleElement.setAttribute("cx", 100);
    circleElement.setAttribute("cy", 100);
    circleElement.setAttribute("r", 80);
    circleElement.setAttribute("fill", "none");
    circleElement.setAttribute("stroke", "green");
    circleElement.setAttribute("stroke-width", 40);
    circleElement.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", "502.85 502.85");

    const svgElement = createSVGElement("svg");
    svgElement.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 200 200");
    svgElement.append(circleElement);

    shadow.appendChild(svgElement);
      
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = `
      svg {
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    `;
    
    shadow.appendChild(style);
  }
}

customElements.define("pie-chart", PieChart);
```

```html
<pie-chart></pie-chart>
```

And since you're using SVG: remember that even though SVG is "part of HTML" ever since HTML5, SVG elements on the JS side still require the use of [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) with the SVG namespace. It's super weird, super inconvenient, but we're stuck with it.

Comment: For all other people who came across this problem and want to save time reading the answer - create SVG elements using Namespace -  document.createElementNS(`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, "SVG"). That was the problem

Comment: @Mike, the ``constructor`` is actually a better place to attach **shadow**DOM; as the ``connectedCallback`` runs later **after** the ``attributeChangedCallback``, and the ``connectedCallback`` _can_ run multiple times when moving Nodes. **Only** the ``constructor`` will run for ``document.createElement("my-component")``; so its the only option if you need to mutate **shadow**DOM **IN** memory.

Comment: very good answer

Answer (score 3):

- Mike is very right when he says the way you `init` your Web Component is wrong.
  The `connectedCallback`  executes when the Web Components *enters* the DOM, so at that time it can ***render/create*** DOM. **No need to dispatch an Event** to yet another **render()** *method*
- The other answer is not completely right when he says to **create shadowDOM** in the `connectedCallback`. You *can*; but you don't want to because the `connectedCallback` ***can*** run multiple times.
  The `constructor` is the perfect place to **create shadowDOM**
- SVG Namespaces are a pain. But the Browser will set the correct NameSpace when you **add content as HTML** (instead of DOM **nodes**)

That gives us:

```html
<script>
customElements.define("pie-chart", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .innerHTML =
          `<style>` +
            `:host{background:grey;display:inline-block}`+
            `svg{--s:120px;width:var(--s);height:var(--s);vertical-align:top}` +
          `</style>` +
          `<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">` +
            `<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%"` +
                   ` fill="none" stroke="pink" stroke-width="15%"` +
                   ` pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="30 15">`+
            `</circle>`+
          `</svg>`;
    this.circle = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("circle");
  }
  static get observedAttributes() { return ["stroke","size","gap"] }
  attributeChangedCallback(name,oldValue,newValue) { this[name] = this.getAttribute(name) }
  get gap()     { return this._gap || 15 }
  set gap(v)    { this._gap = v;this.size = this._size }
  set stroke(v) { this.circle.setAttribute("stroke",v) }
  set size(v)   { this.circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", (this._size = v) + " " + this.gap) }
});
</script>
<pie-chart></pie-chart>
<pie-chart stroke="red"></pie-chart>
<pie-chart stroke="yellow"></pie-chart>
<pie-chart stroke="blue" size="55"></pie-chart>
```

##### Notes

- I added `inline-block` and `vertical-align`
- For the same reason I added `pathLength="360"` because others shouldn't have to deal with weird `stroke-dasharray` fraction values.
- added handling of `attributes`.
- I did https://pie-meister.github.io

So all you need to do is:

```html
<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister.min.js"></script>

<h3>Choose an option</h3>

<pie-chart pulltext="120">
  <style>
    text {
      font: 2em Arial;
      text-anchor: middle;
      fill: white;
    }
  </style>
  <slice size="60%" stroke="#4b77a9">Option 1 $size</slice>
  <slice size="15%" stroke="#5f255f">Option 2 $size</slice>
  <slice size="15%" stroke="#d21243">Option 3 $size</slice>
  <slice size="10%" stroke="#B27200">Option 4 $size</slice>
</pie-chart>
```

Comment: A user with editing privileges has not *rewritten* this post. They simply removed language that unnecessarily attacks the OP. If you decide to undelete this post, please make sure to stick to the technical content. For anything else, raise flags as appropriate.